# Is there a way to access the function of screen component of DrawerNavigator into menu button of DrawerNavigator in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I have a Drawer Navigator which have screens.
Now I want to access the one screen function in menu button of drawer. 
Let suppose

**Drawer Navigator:**

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Main: {
      path: "/Main",
      screen: MainScreen
    },
    LikeScreen: {
      path: "/Like",
      screen: LikeScreen
    },
    DislikeScreen: {
      path: "/Dislike",
      screen: DislikeScreen
    }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Main",
    drawerWidth: widthPercentageToDP("60%"),
    contentComponent: SideMenu,
    headerMode: "screen"
  }
);
```

**MainScreen:**

```
export default class MainScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      TurnMeOnMainFilterModal: false
    };
  }
 _OpenFilterModel=()=> this.setState({ TurnMeOnMainFilterModal: true });
 _closeFilterModel=()=> this.setState({ TurnMeOnMainFilterModal: false });
  render() {
   return <View>
         <Modal
      animationType="slide"
      transparent={true}
      visible={this.state.TurnMeOnMainFilterModal}
      presentationStyle="overFullScreen"
    >
      <View style={Style1.ModalViewContainer}>
        <View style={Style1.ModalView}>
         <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this._closeFilterModel}>
          <View style={Style1.ModalCloseButton}>
            <Icon
            color="#7BB141"
            name="check"
            size={widthPercentageToDP("8%")}
           />
           </View>
         </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
       </View>
       </View>
         </Modal>
       </View>
}
```

**SideMenu:**

```
import { NavigationActions } from "react-navigation";
class SideMenu extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { selected: 1, Language:props.screenProps.Language };
    this.changer = this.changer.bind(this);
  }

  navigateToScreen = (route, num) => () => {
    const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: route });
    this.changer(num);
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);
  };
  changer(Num) {
    this.setState({ selected: Num });
  }
  render() {
    const { Language } = this.state;
    const color1 = "#0DA4D0",
      color2 = "grey";
    return (
      <View style={Style.Parentcontainer}>
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.navigateToScreen("Main", 1)}>
          <View style={Style.ChildUpperContainer}>
            <Icon
              name="home-outline"
              size={widthPercentageToDP("7%")}
              color={this.state.selected === 1 ? color1 : color2}
            />
            <Text
              style={[
                Style.textFont,
                this.state.selected === 1
                  ? { color: color1 }
                  : { color: color2 }
              ]}
            >
              Home
            </Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        {this.state.selected === 1 && (
          <TouchableWithoutFeedback
            onPress={() => {
             ////////////////////(Here I want The Function Of Screen to be access)/////////////////////////
              this.props.navigation.closeDrawer();
            }}
          >
            <View style={Style.ChildUpperContainer}>
              <Icon
                name="filter-outline"
                size={widthPercentageToDP("7%")}
                color={color2}
              />
              <Text style={[Style.textFont, { color: color2 }]}>
                Home Filter
              </Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        )}

        <TouchableWithoutFeedback
          onPress={this.navigateToScreen("LikeScreen", 3)}
        >
          <View style={Style.ChildUpperContainer}>
            <Icon
              name="thumb-up-outline"
              size={widthPercentageToDP("7%")}
              color={this.state.selected === 3 ? color1 : color2}
            />
            <Text
              style={[
                Style.textFont,
                this.state.selected === 3
                  ? { color: color1 }
                  : { color: color2 }
              ]}
            >
              Liked
            </Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback
          onPress={this.navigateToScreen("DislikeScreen", 4)}
        >
          <View style={Style.ChildUpperContainer}>
            <Icon
              name="thumb-down-outline"
              size={widthPercentageToDP("7%")}
              color={this.state.selected === 4 ? color1 : color2}
            />
            <Text
              style={[
                Style.textFont,
                this.state.selected === 4
                  ? { color: color1 }
                  : { color: color2 }
              ]}
            >
              Disliked
            </Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

SideMenu.propTypes = {
  navigation: PropTypes.object
};

export default SideMenu;
```

In the `sidemenu` ,I commented where I want to access `MainScreen's` Function `_OpenFilterModel` to be performed.
Actually I want to open the `Modal` of screen (which will perform more operation on current `screen Component`) through clicking on menu of `Drawer` in which `screen Component` itself is a child.

Answer (score 1):

I end up with my own following solution:

**In MainScreen:**

```
componentWillMount() {
  this.props.navigation.setParams({
      FilterModel: this._OpenFilterModel
   });
 }
```

**In SideMenu:**

```
onPress={() => {
         ////HERE TO CAll
         this.props.navigation.state.routes[0].params.FilterModel();
         this.props.navigation.closeDrawer();
        }}
```

or

```
onPress={() => {
         ////HERE TO CAll
         this.props.items[0].params.FilterModel();
         this.props.navigation.closeDrawer();
        }}
```

routes[0] and items[0] is accordingly to createDrawerNavigator Screen Sequence . `Main Screen` Is at `index 0`.